# find embedded objects (esp flash files) using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm trying to write a javascript function that detects embedded objects. As the result of my 3 hour research i found that there are 2 major approach to use a .swf file in html

1. Object tag, example: `<object data="intro.swf" height="200" width="200"/>`
2. Embed tag, example:`<embed src="intro.swf" height="200" width="200"/>`

But there is a third approach which is cross-browser and somehow more common:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0"
    width="100"
    height="100">
<param name="movie" value="sample.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<embed src="sample.swf" quality="high" width="100" height="100"
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
```

I found a function [here](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/):

```
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName) {
    if (window.document[movieName]) {
        return window.document[movieName];
    }
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet") == -1) {
        if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
            return document.embeds[movieName];
    }
    else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
    {
        return document.getElementById(movieName);
    }
}
```

but this function takes the id/Name Attribute as argument,and is not good for me. 
I thought that it's better to detect browser first and then look for flash object.
I'm still trying.
What should I do to detect RENDERED flash object??

Comment: I once wrote a bookmarklet to find flash, and I remember this fun fact: `object`s can be nested, so there may be an `object` decendant of an `object`. And of course, `embed`s are commonly used as children of `object`s. You need to filter that one out.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

jQuery:

```
$('object:has(embed)');
```

Vanilla JS:

```
function getCompleteObjects () {
    var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object'),
        len = objects.length,
        complete = [],
        i = 0;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        var embed = objects[i].getElementsByTagName('embed');
        if (embed) {
            complete.push(objects[i]);
        }
    }

    return complete;
}
```

jQuery fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/9vFgT/

Vanilla JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/WZEvF/

Comment: Thanks for your answer pal, I knew about `document.embeds` , but what about object tags? It not important for me to know that if the flash has been successfully loaded. I only need to have whole flash objects.

Comment: In IE the `object` tag works and `embed` tag is ignored. but (as I think, I'm not sure) none-IE browsers use embed tag, if `embed` tag is included in object tag (like the third way I mentioned in question).

Comment: I exactly need the flash object, not object/embed tags of a page.

Comment: The Flash object's API is exposed via the DOM object, so practically there's no difference between HTML element and Flash object.

Comment: Thanks Pumbaa80, would tell me What does `[].slice` do?

Comment: There's no way to tell if a Flash object is loaded unless it provides an API (callback or property) for that ([example](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#EventHandlers)). If you know there's some API method you may test for their existence in the DOM element like so: `if ($('#someflash').getPlaylistIndex)`.

Comment: I must not be understanding, but it sounds like `document.embeds` should be good enough.

Comment: `document.embeds` is good , but not all `<object data="sample.swf" width="400" height="150" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</object>` in this example, `document.embeds` does not work, because there is no `embed` tag, but he flash file renders in all browsers.